# Path manipulation issue report by fortify scan

Tags: c#, path-manipulation

I have been fixing fortify issues in our application. below piece of code always reported as path manipulation issue. I don't understand why. There is no user input in this method. Could someone please help me on this I am not able to figure out how to fix this issue. This is c# code

```
 string fileName = CreateConfigFileName(); //Its not a user input. 
 string path =  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CommonFilePath"];
 String finalPath = path + Path.GetFileName(fileName); 
 if (Path.GetFileName(fileName) == fileName && !File.Exists(finalPath))
    {
                File.WriteAllText(finalPath, xmlString);
    }

 private string CreateConfigFileName()
        {
            var fileName = new StringBuilder("LogDetail_");
            var user = enterprise.ConfigUserName;
            var LastModifiedDate = enterprise.LastModifiedDate;
            fileName.Append("_");
            fileName.Append(user);
            fileName.Append("_");
            fileName.Append(LastModifiedDate.Substring(0, 4)).Append("-"); // yyyy
            fileName.Append(LastModifiedDate.Substring(4, 2)).Append("-"); // mm
            fileName.Append(LastModifiedDate.Substring(6, 2)).Append("-"); // dd
            fileName.Append(LastModifiedDate.Substring(8, 2)).Append("-"); // hh
            fileName.Append(LastModifiedDate.Substring(10, 2)).Append("-"); // mm
            fileName.Append(LastModifiedDate.Substring(12, 2)); // ss
            return fileName.Append(".xml").ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Technically, AppSettings is a user input.

Comment: Even if I hardcode it like "c:\\logs\\" still it comes as path manipulation issue

Comment: Show us your hardcoded code that still identifies the path manipulation issue.  Retain the original code in your question.

Comment: See also https://security.stackexchange.com/q/103884

Comment: Alright.  Show us the code for CreateConfigFileName().

Comment: Where does the `enterprise` object get those strings?

Comment: Values comes from database

Comment: The database is a form of input.  I'm sorry to break it to you, but Fortify is right.  Your choices are: 1.  Hard-code it so that it doesn't come from the database, 2. Ignore it.